# Is it technically wrong to use simple "accuracy" in keras model metrics for multi-class classification? Should we use CategoricalAccuracy()?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification, multilabel-classification

So according to Keras definition, simple "accuracy" metrics compare 2 labelled Classes is that correct.
code snippet

```
        ---------some model layers---------.
        model.add(Dense(len(all_labels), name="output", activation = 'softmax'))
        METRICS = ['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy() , tf.keras.metrics.AUC(), 'mae']
        model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
                           metrics = METRICS)
```

I'm trying to solve multi-class image recognition problem(7 classes, mutually exclusive)(one datapoint belongs to only one class), one-hot encoding is used and Output Softmax Activation is used for Multi-class (Is this correct or should I choose Sigmoid?).
The loss function is Binary Crossentropy (Categorical Crossentropy is for multi-label{mutually inclusive}).
So what Accuracy metrics apply here?
'accuracy' or categoricalAccuracy()?

example out--> shows 'accuracy' is high but categoricalAccuracy is bad

```
Epoch 1/10
 99/100 [============================>.] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.5722 - acc: 0.8334 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1504 - auc_2: 0.5117 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2434
```

If this model is bad in terms of Categorical accuracy, how to make it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use CategoricalAccuracy. It works with one-hot labels and predicted logits of classes.

I think that you should use CategoricalCrossentropy as loss function. BinaryCrossentropy is used when you have two classes.